# Issue in Mobile layout

Tags: css, wordpress

Please see the below URL's.

1. http://www.rajnikantvscidjokes.in/7-must-things-arranged-marriage-gets-fixed/
2. http://www.bckutta.net/some-movies-or-books-can-change-your-life-forever/

Theme is same, everything is same but when I am opening the first link in mobile, the alignment is correct but when I am opening the second link, alignment is on left side !

I am working on Second link and I am not able to find the solution. This Problem is happening only in Mobile.

Comment: 1. Show your code, 
2. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Vedant I am new in coding and let me know which code you want ?? Style.css or any other.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment area, you have a hint for the visitors attempting to reply:

> You may use these HTML tags and attributes:
>   `<a href="" title=""> <abbr title=""> <acronym title=""> <b> <blockquote cite=""> <cite> <code> <del datetime=""> <em> <i> <q cite=""> <strike> <strong>`

In which the second line has following CSS rule:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

It tells the browser DO NOT BREAK THIS LINE. As a result, when you visit the page on mobile (or browser on PC in a narrow window), the document width is expanded and exceeds window width, because this line is too long.

[image]

Remove the CSS rule would be a quick and working fix.